# Is there a need to write an application letter when applying for Canadian visas?

Tags: visas, canada, nigerian-citizens, nigeria

Any ideas if I should use an application letter (like a statement of purpose) to explain why I want to apply for Canadian temporary visas etc for visit purposes and all?

Comment: If memory serves one of the required paper you need to attach to apply for a  visitor visa is "purpose of travel". You can include your explanation there.

Answer (score -2):

You must include a covering letter/ statement of purpose. It helps immensely as you are able to explain to visa officer and provide all facts in 1 place. it gives him an overview.

Comment: I do not think *must* is correct - there is no mention of such a letter in the list of supporting documents for a visitor visa application https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/supporting-documents.html

Comment: It is not mandated by embassy to include the covering letter but it is highly advisable. it is like a cover letter where you explain your case and any other points that you could not cover in your application. it helps immensely and in its absence if the visa officer misses any point, it will work to your disadvantage.

Comment: "It is not mandated by embassy to include the covering letter but it is highly advisable.". Your answer says it is mandated ("must"). If that's not the case please edit the answer.